# sql server 2008 function on two date columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I would like to create a function for a table that has three columns amongst others as follows:

```
insertDate datetime
updateDate datetime
activity   integer
```

I want to update the activity column by taking the difference of the two date columns...basically updateDate - insertDate = how many days of activity in the activity column. I have no idea how to start this and it needs to run whenever a new insertDate or updateDate is inserted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can populate the `[InsertDate]` with a default value of `GETDATE()` and populate `[UpdateDate]` with the current date when you update the column (because you're using procedures (*wink*), this is really easy to control). If you aren't using procedures and want to control. the `[UpdateDate]` column, you can use a trigger to populate that column.

Let the `Activity` column be a calculated field:

```
DATEDIFF(day, [InsertDate], [UpdateDate])
```

**[DATEDIFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)**

**[Computed Columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx)**

---

*From MSDNabout computed columns:*

```
Unless otherwise specified, computed columns are virtual columns that are
not physically stored in the table. Their values are recalculated every
time they are referenced in a query. The Database Engine uses the PERSISTED
keyword in the CREATE TABLE and ALTER TABLE statements to physically store
computed columns in the table. Their values are updated when any columns
that are part of their calculation change. By marking a computed column as
PERSISTED, you can create an index on a computed column that is
deterministic but not precise.
```

Comment: +1 For the calculated field idea.  I didn't think of it, and would even be a better solution than the trigger approach. =)

Answer (score 1):

Since all the data required for this is in the same row of the table, you could create a [computed column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx). If you want to have an actual column value that is updated whenever the row is updated then you need to look at [triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Place this code in a trigger.

```
update MyTable
    set updateDate = GETDATE()
        , activity = select (DATEDIFF(DAY, insertDate, GETDATE()))
```